# jQuery html selector succeeds when loading the web page from the local file system but fails when loading it online

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, match

```
$("> html").length
```

The above statement results in 1 in chrome and 0 in IE and Firefox UPDATE: It results in 1 in all browsers as long as the web page displayed is loaded from a file in the local file system. If the web page is online then the result is 0 across the board. Trivial question I know but I couldn't find anything relevant. Was just wondering which of the two behaviors is the correct one. Thanks in advance.

Update:

I've created the following trivial html file to toy around with the dev tools of the various browsers:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Gives me a 0 in Chrome too (ran it in my console on this page). What version of jQuery are we talking about? SO uses 1.7.1 so this behavior might only be present in the newest version

Comment: I noticed when using jQuery 1.8.2 ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/Rtahz/)), it returns 1 on all latest of Chrome, IE & Firefox for me.  As soon as I change it to jQuery 1.7.2, it shows 0, in the same three browsers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did this come about?  What is it you were trying to do and what was your expected result?

Comment: This behavior isn't documented anywhere, so it's hard to say whether it's correct or incorrect behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responses. I think that the reason I was getting 1 with chrome was because I was loading the web page directly from my local file system. When I loaded the web page in the same fashion using the other browsers I started getting the same result. Funny thing that the result is 0 when the test web page is online. The parent of the html element for local html files turns out to be the document element. I will turn this into the answer if nothing else comes up. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the parent of the html element is the document element, provided that the web page is loaded directly from a local html file.

When loading the exact same web page from an http server the html element has no parent.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use

```
$("html").length
```

instead? After all html should not be a descendant of anything.